# Save, Delete, & Manage the Google Hangout Video Calls by using API?

Tags: google-plus

I'd like to know , whether we can Save, Delete, & Manage the Google+ Hangout Video Calls by using API? If yes, may I know which API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends exactly what you mean by "save, delete, and manage", but in general the answer will be no.

The [Hangout API](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/) is used for apps running inside the hangout itself. You can do some manipulation of the video stream, but there is no way to directly access the video itself.

If you are running this as a Hangout on Air, you may be able to use the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) to mananage the recordings the way you want.